# Error when upgrading to 4.6.9 on Drupal 7

Tags: upgrade

I received a string of nine similar error messages when trying to upgrade to version 4.6.9.  There is also a smarty error message.  Please dan you help?  This is the first time I have attempted an upgrade.
Regards
Graham

•   Warning: opendir(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/xml/Menu/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in CRM_Utils_File::getFilesByExtension() (line 428 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php).
•   Warning: opendir(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/xml/Menu/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in CRM_Utils_File::getFilesByExtension() (line 428 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php).

User warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "CRM/common/success.tpl" in Smarty->trigger_error() (line 1094 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php).

Comment: Looks like you don't have all of the files in the right place

Comment: Thank you but not sure where to look next. I did check and all the files referred to do exist.

Comment: Thanks Hershel.  You were correct.  I unpacked the 4.6.9 version and it created a scicrm sub directory.  I moved the files up to the parent and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Errors such as 'No such file or directory' or 'Failed to open resource' normally suggest that CiviCRM couldn't find certain files where it was expecting to.

The first thing to check is that all your CiviCRM files have been put in the correct place according to the installation/upgrade documentation; and the configuration in your settings file.

This was answered by Hershel and in this case CiviCRM had been unpacked into a sub-directory.